# Redshift serializable error on getting data in table a not in table b based on 2 keys

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am running this query:

```
with cte as
(select distinct maker_addr,token1_id as tkn_id from updation_table ut 
union
select distinct maker_addr,token0_id as tkn_id from updation_table ut)
select * from cte
where (maker_addr,tkn_id) not in (select maker_addr,token_id from makeraddr_tokenid_properties mtp);
```

but this error is being shown

> SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: 1023
>    Detail: Serializable isolation
> violation on table - 308739, transactions forming the cycle are:
> 5108879, 5091071 (pid:1073955294)

I tried to change the query

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT maker_addr, token1_id AS tkn_id FROM updation_table
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT maker_addr, token0_id AS tkn_id FROM updation_table) AS sq
WHERE (maker_addr, tkn_id) NOT IN (SELECT maker_addr, token_id FROM makeraddr_tokenid_properties);
```

but same error

Answer (score 0):

A "Serializable isolation violation" is a coherency error that occurs between 2 transactions.  You SQL is for 1 statement in 1 of these transactions.  The issue is described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_serial_isolation.html

In essence a coherency "loop" has been created where statement A is updating table X based on table Y while at the same time statement B is updating table Y based on table X (as an example).  To resolve this type of error you need to find the SQL for both transactions including every statement in each transaction.

While the provided statement is important it is not whole story.  You will want to go into svl_statementtext and pull all the statements for the transactions ids (xid) provided (5108879, 5091071) and look up the table name for the table provided (308739).  Be advised that transaction ids (xid) are recycled over time so you will want to be sure to limit these lookups to the timeframe of the error.

With this information you can update your question with enough information so that the community can assist.

If you don't know how to do these xid lookups here's an example from a past debug I've done:

```
select xid, pid, starttime, max(datediff('sec',starttime,endtime)) as runtime, type, listagg(regexp_replace(text,'\\\\n*',' ')) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sequence) || ';' as querytext
  from svl_statementtext
  where xid = 5108879
    and sequence < 320
    and starttime > getdate() - interval '24 hours'
  group by starttime, 1, 2, "type" 
  order by starttime, 1 asc, "type" desc ;
```

You will need to run something like this for both xids provided in the error message.